# Semi-transparent 2d VTK text background

Tags: python, vtk

Simple question, but I've tried a few things and nothing seems to work.

I want to overlay some statistics onto a 3d VTK scene, using 2D `vtkTextActor`s. This works fine, but the text is at times difficult to see, depending on what appears behind it in the 3D scene.

For this reason, I'd like to add a 2d, semi-transparent "box" behind my text actors to provide a darker background.

Which VTK object is appropriate for this? I've tried so far:

- `vtkLegendBoxActor`: Not what I want, but I can use this with no text to display a semi-transparent box on screen. I cannot size it directly and I get warnings about not initialising some of the content.
- `vtkImageData`: Tried manually creating image data and adding it to the scene; I believe it was placed within the 3d scene and not used as an overlay. If that's not the case then I couldn't get it to show at all.
- `vtkCornerAnnotation`: Scales with window size, is fixed to a corner and the background opacity cannot be set AFAIK.
- `vtkTextActor`: Cannot set a background color or opacity

Can anyone tell me how they might achieve what I'm after in VTK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a way to do this with `vtkPolyMapper2D` which seems to work okay. It seems to be a very stupid way to do this. If there is something more elegant, I'm all ears.

```
import vtk
extents = [[0,0],[620,0],[620,220],[0,220]]

polyPoints = vtk.vtkPoints()

for x, y in extents:
    polyPoints.InsertNextPoint(x, y, 0)

num_corners = len(extents)
polyCells = vtk.vtkCellArray()
polyCells.InsertNextCell(num_corners + 1)

for i in range(0, num_corners):
    polyCells.InsertCellPoint(i)

polyCells.InsertCellPoint(0) ## Rejoin at the end

poly_profile = vtk.vtkPolyData()
poly_profile.SetPoints(polyPoints)
poly_profile.SetPolys(polyCells) ## Goes solid

cut_triangles = vtk.vtkTriangleFilter()
cut_triangles.SetInput(poly_profile)

_poly_mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper2D()
_poly_mapper.SetInput(poly_profile)
_poly_mapper.SetInputConnection(cut_triangles.GetOutputPort())

_actor = vtk.vtkActor2D()
_actor.SetMapper(_poly_mapper)
_actor.GetProperty().SetColor([0.1,0.1,0.1])
_actor.GetProperty().SetOpacity(0.5)
#Add to renderer as normal
```

Answer (score 0):

just use vtktexture, vtkimagedata & add your own image as texture background to the vtkrenderer by reducing the opacity like a watermark. thats it

Comment: Could you perhaps include a small example explaining how one would go about accomplishing this?